# MATLAB: Reading data from a text file with string in last line and "merged" columns

Tags: matlab, file-io, header

I have some simulation results stored in a large text file formatted similarly to the following example:

```
******* Information
More Information

    Header 1   Header 2   Header 3
    [Unit]     [Unit]     [Unit]

    12345      67890      12345
    12345      67890      12345
end
```

What is an easy way to import this into MATLAB without having to manually edit the file beforehand? I know I can skip header lines, but what can I do about the `end` in the last line? Until now I have always used `load()` and manually deleted the header and the last line, but I would like to get rid of that extra step.

Besides, the entries of one column sometimes get so big that they border on the previous column (making it one), e.g.

```
12345  678
12345 6789
1234567890
```

`load()` obviously fails to import my data when this happens. What can I do about this?

You can find an abridged version of the original dataset [here](http://pastebin.com/x3gcsgL3). My second problem occurs in the the `sum(Evap)` and `TLevel` columns of line 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html). You could use something like

```
data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f', 'HeaderLines', 6);
```

which will read all of the data until it hits the "end" (which doesn't match its expected format). This won't take care of the problem of data columns running together though. That would probably be easiest to fix on the data generation side of things if you can.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. My code just in case anyone else working with HYDRUS 1D (I couldn't create a new tag, unfortunately) stumbles upon this: `nCol = 22; formatSpec = repmat('%f', 1, nCol); fileID = fopen('T_Level.out'); data = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'HeaderLines', 9); fclose(fileID);`. I guess I will fix the problem with the data columns manually, it's only two or three occurences anyway.